# How can i pass a list from my first form to a second form, add data to it and then show it on my first form? C#

Tags: c#, list, forms

From what i've read so far i've done this:
On my first form:

```
public partial class FPrincipal : Form
{
    List<Grua> ListaGruas = new List<Grua>();
    List<Semirremolques> ListaSemirremolques = new List<Semirremolques>();
    List<Clientes> ListaClientes = new List<Clientes>();
    
    // this is the menu strip i click to create my new form,  
    // send my list and add my values

    private void miEquipoCargar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EquiposCargar FormEquiposCargar = new EquiposCargar(ListaGruas);
        FormEquiposCargar.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

And on my second form:

```
public partial class EquiposCargar : Form
{
    // I saw some videos on youtube and this is how the pass some values, 
    // but it doesnt work with lists
    public EquiposCargar(List<Grua>listaGrua)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

Could anyone please help me? im stuck.
The error says the parameter `List<Grua>listaGrua` is less accesible than the method `EquiposCargar.EquiposCargar(List<Grua>)`

Comment: Can you add the definition of the class _Grua_? Is it a public class?

Comment: no its not public! i just changed it and the error is gone!

Comment: @Steve thank you! now the error is gone, but is that the correct way to pass data through forms? it looks like it could work

Comment: Yes this is probably the simplest way to do it. You can also create a property on the receiving form and set it with that list before showing the form. You can also avoid to pass anything and create an event handler in the main form to be called from the second form with the data to add to the list.

Comment: @Steve thank you so much!!!!!!

Comment: @Steve just another question! how do i use the list on my second form? lol... because it says the name listaGrua is not defined in the actual content. It looks like i have to create a new variable and assign the list parameter than i sent, right? but im doing it and its still not working

Answer (score 0):

> just another question! how do i use the list on my second form? lol...
> because it says the name listaGrua is not defined in the actual
> content. It looks like i have to create a new variable and assign the
> list parameter than i sent, right? but im doing it and its still not
> working

That's correct, you need to create a variable in your second form to hold that reference.  In the constructor, simply assign the passed in reference to your form's reference:

```
public partial class EquiposCargar : Form
{

    private List<Grua> listaGrua;

    public EquiposCargar(List<Grua> listaGrua)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.listaGrua = listaGrua;
    }
    
}
```

Note the use of the `this` keyword.  Now you should be able to use `listaGrua` from anywhere in your second form.

Comment: thanks! im so stressed out, the list works on the second form.. but when i want to show it on my first form it just shows the name of the object "Hidrogrua.Grua" .. it doesnt show all the content i saved on the list (which is the object Grua, with the setters and getters and the override .ToString() function...). I dont know what could it be, the list is public, maybe when i close the second form.. everything i saved on the list dissappears? but whyyy im going crazy

Comment: In what, and how, are you trying to display the list?

Comment: in a listbox, i created a new question, if you could read it i'd appreciate it. I posted pictures too

Comment: I don't see your other question yet.  One way is to simply set the [DataSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.datasource?view=netcore-3.1) property of the listbox to your list.  If the DataSource had been set previously, you can refresh the listbox by settting DataSource to null, then setting it right back to the same  DataSource.

Comment: Other ways are to use the Items.AddRange() method, or iterate over the list with a foreach and Add() each individual item.